# Posting to a WEB API from Perl results in a null value in [FromBody]

Tags: perl, asp.net-web-api

We have created a WEB API (in .NET framework 4.0) and gave the endpoint info to one of our clients. They created a program in Perl that posts to our endpoint.

Every post they have made so far arrives into our endpoint as null. When we initially started programming, we had that same issue in JQuery when posting by means of $.ajax. We solved it by adding a '=' at the beginning of the post data.

The Perl code they have submitted is the following:

```
sub _postPackages {
    my ($self,$dataToSend) = @_;


    use LWP::UserAgent;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->agent("integrationapp/1.0 ");

    # Create a request
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $self->{postAddress} );

    $req->content_type("application/json;charset=utf-8");
    $req->content($dataToSend->{data});

    #print Data::Dumper->Dump([$req]);

    # Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

where **postAddress** is our endpoint and **$dataToSend** is the message data. Is it possible that they need to add the '=' at the beginning of the **$dataToSend** message.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your `$dataToSend` containing JSON? How is your message data and your controller action looks like?

Comment: could you show a working jquery ajax snippet for comparison?  what led you to decide to add a `=`?

Comment: Why aren't you using the UserAgent to POST the request as well?

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. I'll try to answer as amany comments as I can.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. I'll try to answer as many comments as I can. @nemesv The $datasend does contain the JSON the controller action looks like this: **public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string package)
        
        { ...the rest of the code ..** .

Comment: @ysth - This is the code that we are using to invoke the WEB Api from Jquery: $.ajax({
            url: api_url,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify('=' + messagedata),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data.length);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Status: ' + xhr.status + ', Error Thrown: ' + thrownError);

            }
        });

Comment: @chrsblck - This was provided by our client. I am not that well versed in Perl.. :-( Sorry...

Comment: again, why =?  your ajax is sending a POST request with a content-type indicating it is json, but it isn't actually json (because of the =)

Comment: in other words, it looks to me like the only bug here is in your server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of pseudo code here..

But I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
# some post sub
my ($self, $data) = @_; 
my $ua = $self->get_user_agent();
my $json_xs = $self->get_json_xs();

my $json_encoded = $json_xs->utf8->encode($data);
$self->set_post_data($json_encoded);
$self->set_api_call();

my $response_body = $ua->post(
    $self->get_api_call(),
    'Content'      => $self->get_post_data(),
    'Content-type' => "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
);  
print STDERR "POSTING NEW RESOURCE: " . Dumper($self);
```